# How to use Python Crawler to crawl second line text

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl url in the second line from this website: https://www.cwb.gov.tw/V7/js/HDRadar_1000_n_val.js.

I use python to crawl but not sure if I should use beautifulsoup or regular expression.

I use python BS4 to crawl. But I don't know how to capture only second line with only url. In my try, it's capturing all of the website.

```py
import requests

import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.cwb.gov.tw/V7/js/HDRadar_1000_n_val.js')

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

#### Expected:

```
/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271140.png
```

#### Actual:

```
var HDRadar_1000_n_val=new Array( new
Array/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271140.png("2019/03/27 11:40","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271140.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 11:30","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271130.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 11:20","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271120.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 11:10","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271110.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 11:00","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271100.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 10:50","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271050.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 10:40","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271040.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 10:30","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271030.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 10:20","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271020.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 10:10","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271010.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 10:00","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903271000.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 09:50","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270950.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 09:40","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270940.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 09:30","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270930.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 09:20","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270920.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 09:10","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270910.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 09:00","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270900.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 08:50","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270850.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 08:40","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270840.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 08:30","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270830.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 08:20","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270820.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 08:10","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270810.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 08:00","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270800.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 07:50","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270750.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 07:40","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270740.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 07:30","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270730.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 07:20","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270720.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 07:10","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270710.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 07:00","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270700.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 06:50","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270650.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 06:40","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270640.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 06:30","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270630.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 06:20","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270620.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 06:10","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270610.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 06:00","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270600.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 05:50","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270550.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 05:40","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270540.png"), new Array("2019/03/27 05:30","/V7/observe/radar/Data/HD_Radar/CV1_1000_201903270530.png"),
```

...

Comment: Why do you expect to only get the second line? - I think this is actually all one line

Comment: I want to use this result to get only the url

Comment: Then you have to perform more processing on the text you get back.  And soup probably won't do you any good, as it's a HTML parser, and this is Javascript code.

Comment: oh! it is one line...thanks  But how can I get url

Comment: Do you know how to use regular expressions at all?  That would be a great thing to use here.

Comment: I know how to get it, but if I just told you, you wouldn't learn anything.  Why don't you start with something simple, like searching in result string for `"/V7"`? When you find that, then search from there for `".png"`

Comment: use RE or maybe which direction? thanks,Steve

Comment: yes,that's what I want to get from /V7....to png

Comment: It can take a little time to learn RE.  It's worth it though.  You can do truly MAGIC things with REs.

Comment: So use basic string search methods to find those two substrings.  Then you know where the substring is that you want, and you can just pull it out.

Comment: I will try it in regular expressions. Thanks

Comment: Ok, cool.  I'm really good with RE, so you can ask me questions if you need to, and I'll know what to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to parse text with `bs4`.
So, make a list of lines by using `split`. Then go through each line & split the `,` separator to get the `url`.

```
lines = res.text.strip(');\n').split('),\n')
for line in lines:
    print(line.split(',')[-1].strip('"'))
```

Comment: @Steve can you tell me where is the problem because I don't see any problem or error in my code.

Comment: Sorry.  I was trusting what he put in his answer, but that's not what the data actually looks like.  I think your code is fine.  Or at least, it doesn't have the problem I thought it did :) - I didn't think there were EOLs.  I thought it was all on one line because of how his version is displayed. - my answer doesn't care about EOLs, so I didn't notice my assumption was wrong. - ran your code.  works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
import requests
import re

res = requests.get('https://www.cwb.gov.tw/V7/js/HDRadar_1000_n_val.js')

pat = re.compile("(/V7/.*?.png)")
p = 0
while True:
    m = pat.search(res.text, p)
    if not m:
        break
    print m.group(1)
    p = m.end()
```

This should be very efficient.  No extra copies or splits of the original data, and a compiled regex is a really fast way to search through data.

Any solution that gets the right result and does it in under a second should be fine.  You'd probably need a much bigger list for it to matter.